# Not getting Firebase Performance Monitoring Alerts emails

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I have integrated the Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK into an Android App. I have made some rest api calls and I can see those response traces also in Performance Dashboard.
I used the app for a day or two to fed some data into the dashboard.

Integrated SDK Details: firebase-bom:32.7.0

root level gradle file:
`plugins { id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf") version "1.4.2" apply false }`

module level Gradle file:
`plugins { id("com.google.gms.google-services") id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")}`

`implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0")) implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf")`

However, When I turned on the Alert on the logged URL network trace as shown below, I am not getting any email.

Appreciate your help.
[image]

[image]
I have tried feeding data for 2 days and integrated the latest sdk's as per the documentation.